# Is it possible to create a "weak export" in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, dead-code, tree-shaking

One unfortunate thing about testing modular code is that sometimes you have to export things just to test them. This pollutes your code, and it also makes nice features like "unused variable" flags on the compiler or linter less valuable - if you remove a usage in your application, you may still have a usage in your tests.

One possible solution would be something like a "weak reference", where test code would refer to the thing it's testing, but with an explicit "linter, compiler: please don't count this reference as a usage" flag.

I checked both the `tsc` flags and `tslint` config documents, but didn't see anything. A) did I miss something? B) is this a good idea and how hard would it be to implement?

(Other solutions just aren't as nice. For example, you could not export things and then use `rewire` to do introspection on the module to get at private things. My understanding is that the tsc would not be able to follow such a reference.)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `unused *` will not work for anything exported anyway and I would not export anything that is not meant to be part of the public API of the module, I would only test the public API of the module, I would not focus on the private implementation details. But to address your question I don't think there is a way to do this, there is an undocumented compiler flag that tells the compiler to include an export in the `d.ts` or not but I am not sure that will help in this case.

Comment: If you compile your application without the tests, a tree-shaker should be able to drop all unused functions anyway

Answer (score 0):

Separate them in to a different module and that way you can  test it more easily. Say you have the following use case.

```
function a () {/* implementation */}
export function b () {
   //... code
   a()
  //..code
}
```

if 'a' was on a different module and required by 'b' your test can then directly require that module. It might also be useful to use inversion of control for module ('b') dependencies. This will allow you to inject mocks/ spys and test it better. In our a/b example it should look something like this.

```
import {a} from './a'
export function CreateB(aFunc:a = a){
  return function b(){
    //..code
    aFunc()
    //..code
  }
}
```

If you will provide a more concrete example I might be able to assist further help more.